# Adobe InDesign: Lines of text are not lining up despite tab being set

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, typesetting

In InDesign, I have a text frame for which I have adjusted the Tab-Settings `(Type -> Tabs)` so that the first tab starts at `10mm`. In the text frame I currently have two lines of text, each having being set to the same typeface ([Akzidenz-Grotesk Next](http://www.bertholdtypes.com/font/akzidenz-grotesk-next-family/pro/))  but different type sizes, `6pt` and `30pt`. Despite the tab having been set for the entire text frame, the two lines of text are not starting at the exact same vertical point; the second line, the one with a 30pt type size, start a little further inward (in the screenshot below I have added a guide to show what I mean).

Why is that? Is it because there is some sort of margin or padding set within the typefaces' font file? How can I make sure that these two lines line up vertically?

[image: Lines of text not lining up exactly]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you need to use the `Optical Margin Alignment` feature, found under `Window > Type > Story` menu entry. Select the paragraphs you need to adjust and check the `Optical Margin Alignment` checkbox, then play with the value in the box. You will probably need a value close to 30pt, but see what works with your styles.

This feature is mainly used to [push quotation marks/punctuation](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/using-type-tools/optical-margin-alignment-in-indesign) outside a text frame, but will also optically align differently sized text styles.

There is plenty more [documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_margin_alignment) on this feature online, some of which will also explain *why* fonts behave this way.

[image]