# Indesign: how to remove the white space between the text and the left side of a text box?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting, formatting

To the right side by default, it seems to do it right but always leaves me a white space to the left.

Is it possible to set the text close to the left text box's margin? Thanks.

[image: Space between text and left side of the text box]

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That space is always there because of the way fonts are being built. What you can do is adjust this optically via the 'Window → Type & Tables → Story' panel. Enable the 'Optical Margin Alignment' feature and play with the value below until it looks right.

Also look at [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82195/adobe-indesign-lines-of-text-are-not-lining-up-despite-tab-being-set) which is similar, but more detail is being given.

[image]